# WebAudio - separate audio channels

Tags: html, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I have 2 separate audio files, that will play through the WebAudio API.

One contains background music and will always be on.
The other contains speech, and my graphics will react to the pitch of the sound. I have a working bit of code that uses the WebAudio.context together with an analyserNode and a dynamicNode to figure out the pitch of the currently playing sound file.

```
function init() {    
    this.context = ((Object)(createjs.WebAudioPlugin)).context;
    this.analyserNode = this.context.createAnalyser();
    this.analyserNode.fftSize = 32;
    this.analyserNode.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.7;
    this.analyserNode.connect(this.context.destination);

    this.dynamicsNode = ((Object)(createjs.WebAudioPlugin)).dynamicsCompressorNode;
    this.dynamicsNode.disconnect();
    this.dynamicsNode.connect(this.analyserNode);

    this.freqFloatData = new Float32Array(this.analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);
    this.freqByteData = new Uint8Array(this.analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);
}

function onUpdate() {
    this.analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(this.freqByteData);
    // ---- do stuff with this.freqByteData[0]; ---- \\
}
```

However, when i play the background music and the speech file simultaneously, i can only retrieve the pitch of both sounds as one.

Is it possible, through the WebAudio API, to get the pitch from a single sound file, while multiple are playing?

Comment: I think the question is too broad for SO as this is a complex field and the result will depend on many many factors. If your speech is in mono and music stereo you could try (multi-step) [phase cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_Of_Phase_Stereo) which has a relative low overhead.

Comment: How are the source node created and connected to the destination node? It would clear up the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "can I apply equalization only to the music tracks, and have the speech sounds unaffected" the answer is yes, definitely - equalization (and other filtering) is an inline effect, it doesn't need to be applied globally.  If you mean "I have source material with speech and music mixed, can I separate them" then Ken's right, that's a much harder challenge.

Comment: But Chris, they can do it on CSI, so... ?

Comment: BWAHAHAHA!  Well, then it must be true.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry i penned down such a crappy question, but you seem to have missed my original intentions completly! I've updated my question to reflect my real problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, that's more clear - but you don't show what you're connecting to the DynamicsCompressorNode (i.e. how you're playing your two tracks).  If you connect one to the DynamicsCompressorNode, and one directly to the context.destination, it should work.